# set_value retain data using callback in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi i have this registration form and i am adding a value which has  a set_value so that the data will remain if submit button i clicked. i am adding a callback which will check the username if already exists on the database. What ive noticed is that my set_value will not work so the data will not remain. when i remove the callback in the username the set_value will work. How will i able to do this? that my set_value will remain. Here is my code below

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|callback_check_username');
```

and my callback code

```
  public function check_username($username){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $result = $this->um->username($username);
    if($result){
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username', 'Username Already Exists.');
      return false; 
    }
  }
```

and my views which has the set_value

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('username');?>" name="username" />
```

any help is muchly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your callback returns anything other than a boolean TRUE/FALSE it is assumed that the data is your newly processed form data.

```
public function check_username($username)
{
   $username = $this->input->post('username');
   $result = $this->um->username($username);
   if($result)
   {
       $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username', 'Username Already Exists.');
       return FALSE;
   } else {
       return TRUE;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks ive got it. i just added the else return true; same as your code

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameter username to view

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
  $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
  $this->load->view('yourviewname',$data);
}
```